# Vertical alignment of array inside tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, arrays

I would like to vertically align several table cells, one of which includes an `array`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{m{0.2\textwidth}}}
    Some text &
    \includegraphics[width=15mm]{example-grid-100x100pt} &
    \(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{array}\right)\) &
    \((1,0,1,0)\) &
    \rule{15mm}{15mm}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Which yields (green reference line added by me):

[image: actual output]

The text, image, simple inline math, and rule are all correctly aligned vertically, but the `array` is pushed down. Instead I would have expected the following:

[image: expected output]

Why is the array not centered vertically? What is the easiest way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in your `\rule` (where it has baseline?). If you encapsulate it in a some box, to which you can define baseline, for example with help of the macro `\valign` from the `\adjustbox`, the same do for image in the second column, than all elements of tabular in `p` columns type will have baseline vertical centered:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % also load graphicx package
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr0.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}} 
    Some text &
    \includegraphics[width=15mm,valign=c]{example-grid-100x100pt} &
    \(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1
    \end{array}\right)\) &  \((1,0,1,0)\) & \adjustbox{valign=c}{\rule{15mm}{15mm}}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text border)

As you can see, I also change columns width that table can fit in text area.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem! Maybe it's also worth mentioning in your answer that you changed the table layout from `m` to `p`, which I overlooked at first. With `m`, the vertical centering is still off, but using `p` and `\adjustbox` works perfecty fine!

Comment: @einbandi, you are right. I should mentioned this too. I will extend my explanation in answer asap.